# How to link two Actionscript files to a .fla file?

Tags: actionscript-3

The .fla file only gives you the option to link one .src file in the 'Class' bit, is there any way to link two .as files to the .fla file?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the second file about, does it concern a specific point of your application? Is it already a class?

Comment: You can do var myshape:Shape = new Shape(); addchild(myshape); myshape.graphics.beginFill(0); myshape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100); but this is another question. You may remove this one and create a new one about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, it's me again (sorry). Is it possible to convert the 'myshape:Shape = new Shape(); addchild(myshape); myshape.graphics.beginFill(0); myshape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);' code you just entered to a 'symbol'? basically, I've done it similar to yours, but I want to convert it to a symbol possibly.

Comment: You can link a symbol in your library to an external class (right click=> properties => Class). If it doesn't answer your question I really don't understand what you mean :)

Comment: just stick that code in your document class. You dont actually need the symbol in the library. If you do, well then do what Kodiak said above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one document class (which corresponds to a .as file), however every symbol can have a class associated with it as well. This gives you in essence an unlimited amount of .as files that are associated with the .fla file.

To create a document class:

1. Go to the properties window; under the Publish section, there is an empty field where you can name your class.
2. Name it whatever you'd like (most likely a similar name to your .fla file). Clicking the pencil will prompt the creation of this class, which will automatically open a new .as file for you.

To create a class for a symbol:

1. Go to the Library tab; Right click where the symbols normally go and click 'New Symbol'.
2. Name your symbol, then click the checkbox 'Export for ActionScript'. Fill in the Class field with what you want your .as file to be named.